# Picker renderer height/placement adjustment?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, uipickerview

[image: cap]

I'm new to Xamrin.Forms programming. I would like to customize the 'Picker' View control. In the picture above there is:

-Button with the text 'Select' (when clicked calls picker.Focus()),
-Picker with both black background and text colors behind the select button,
-Empty ListView,
-The picker options wheel pane, pops up when a picker is  'Focused'

How to either, a) move the wheel pane into the blank ListView, or, b) lengthen the height of the wheel pane (to cover more of the screen)? Examples via PS:

[image: duo]

Picker renderer implementation code, as it is now (provided by @Land):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace AppName.iOS
{
    public class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            UITextField textField = Control;
            UIPickerView pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;
            Picker myPicker = Element;
            List<string> itemList;
            itemList = myPicker.Items.ToList();
            pickerView.Delegate = new MyPickerViewDelegate(itemList);
        }
    }

    public class MyPickerViewDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate
    {
        List<string> itemList;

        public MyPickerViewDelegate(List<string> list)
        {
            itemList = list;
        }

        //Define the Font size or style
        public override NSAttributedString GetAttributedTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            var text = new NSAttributedString(
                itemList[(int)row],
                font: UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12),
                foregroundColor: UIColor.Black,
                strokeWidth: 1
            );

            return text;
        }

        //Define the row height
        public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            return 20;
        }

        //Customize more flexible (including placement) use following method:

        public override UIView GetView(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view)
        {
            UIView contentView = new UIView(new CGRect(
                0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height));

            UILabel label = new UILabel();
            label.Frame = contentView.Bounds;
            contentView.AddSubview(label);

            label.Text = itemList[(int)row];
            //Change the label style
            label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12);
            label.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
            label.TextAlignment = UIKit.UITextAlignment.Center;

            return contentView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) move the wheel pane into the blank ListView

It is by design that UITextField's inputView will fly into view from bottom. If you do want to put it in your ListView. You can try to create a new control instead of Picker.

> b) lengthen the height of the wheel pane (to cover more of the
>   screen)?

Yes we can do that by setting the inputView's frame like:

```
UIPickerView pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;
textField.InputView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 320, 320);
```

But when we do this, it will overlap the inputAccessoryView(with a "Done" button for selecting items). So we need to customize this view too:

```
UIView accessoryView = new UIView(new CGRect(100, 100, 320, 144));
UIButton btn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
btn.SetTitle("Done", UIControlState.Normal);
btn.AddTarget((sender, args) =>
{
    textField.Text = itemList[(int)(pickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(0))];
    textField.ResignFirstResponder();
}, UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
accessoryView.AddSubview(btn);
//Place the button at super view's top, right position.
btn.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
accessoryView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(btn, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, accessoryView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, -10));
accessoryView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(btn, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, accessoryView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 5));

textField.InputAccessoryView = accessoryView;
```

Adjust the last parameter of `CGRect()` to satisfy your requirement of **lengthen the height of the wheel pane**(In my test, the default height of InputView is about 220, of InputAccessoryView is about 44. Adjust them in corresponding).

Comment: @jtth Since we override the picker, the event should be reset. I just give a UI sample, actually we should do much to achieve our effect. I make a sample for you, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/lt0526/CustomPickerRenderer).

Comment: Thanks for the sample. The SelectedIndex is now changing properly. However I still do not know how to overlay the Done button on top of the picker wheel pane (as it comes by default). Using your Picker renderer, we are moving the Done button above the picker wheel rather then the Done button being superimposed on the wheel pane. This must be possible if this is how the picker appears by default yes?

Comment: @jtth I know it may be not a perfect solution, but the inputView is defined by Apple we can't change its feature. And we always use its default height. I also understand official renderer uses toolbar, besides we always use it. But it can't achieve your effect, I change it to view and you can modify its height and background color. It will also work well.

Comment: `accessoryView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(207, 212, 218);`